# Compound Join doesn't display any data. MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

So, I've been following a tutorial: https://youtu.be/7S_tz1z_5bA?t=6638

And when i do the compound join it just doesn't display any data just the column names.

code:

```
SELECT *
FROM order_item_notes oin
JOIN order_items oi
    ON oi.order_id = oin.order_id AND oin.product_id = oi.product_id
```

[What the MySQL Workbench displays.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZg28.png)

I couldnt find any issue similar to my problem, but maybe is the way it works this join? but it wouldnt make sense to me anyways, HELP ME.

thx in advance. :)

Edit: data from the tables that should be displaying.

[Table order_items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQgUC.png)

[Table order_item_notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoaWW.png)

Solved in the comments.

Comment: Looks like it should produce something can you add sample data please.

Comment: @P.Salmon just updated it, is that what u needed?

Comment: I would not expect this query to produce a result based on the posted data since oin has productid 2 for order 1 but order 1 does not have product id 2.

Comment: @P.Salmon you are a genius thank you so much i was losing my mind over this lmao

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query